# CSV удаление строк Python

Tags: python, csv, матрицы

В текстовом csv-файле находится матрица

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
1 3 5 7 9 7 5 3
3 1 5 3 2 6 5 7
1 7 5 9 7 3 1 5
2 6 3 5 1 7 3 2
```

Процедура копирует данную матрицу и записывает её в новый csv-файл, как сделать что бы в новый файл копировалась данная матрица БЕЗ последних 4 строк

```
import csv
file_in= open("tekst.csv",'r')
file_out = open("tekst_g.csv",'w')
file_out.write(file_in.read())
```

Comment: что мешает просто считать построчно сначала в массив `arr`, а потом записать в файл массив `arr[:-4]`?

Comment: Я не знал, что так можно

Comment: Куда нужно массив `arr` добавить? Можно пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как-то так можно сделать в самом простом случае

```
# считать файл построчно
file_in = open('tekst.csv', 'r') 
lines = file_in.readlines() 

# записать строки без последних 4 в файл
file_out = open('tekst_g', 'w') 
file_out.writelines(lines[:-4])
```